# Detecting rows and cell inside a table to search for checkmark

Tags: c++, opencv, cell

I need to detect tables in a document image and, for each one, detect the row number and identify checkmarked cells.

Here is my source image: 
[image]

I've followed this [example](http://answers.opencv.org/question/63847/how-to-extract-tables-from-an-image) and I am able to get three separate images containing one table each one.

Now I need help with the code to process a single table to detect checkmark cells for each row.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
// Load source image
string filename = "questions.png";
Mat src = imread(filename);

// Check if image is loaded fine
if(!src.data)
    cerr << "Problem loading image!!!" << endl;

 // Show source image
  imshow("src", src);

// resizing for practical reasons
Mat rsz;
Size size(800, 900);
resize(src, rsz, size);

imshow("rsz", rsz);

// Transform source image to gray if it is not
Mat gray;

if (rsz.channels() == 3)
{
    cvtColor(rsz, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
}
else
{
    gray = rsz;
}

 // Show gray image
 imshow("gray", gray);

// Apply adaptiveThreshold at the bitwise_not of gray, notice the ~ symbol
Mat bw;
adaptiveThreshold(~gray, bw, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 15, -2);

// Show binary image
imshow("binary", bw);

 // Create the images that will use to extract the horizonta and vertical lines
Mat horizontal = bw.clone();
Mat vertical = bw.clone();

int scale = 15; // play with this variable in order to increase/decrease the amount of lines to be detected

// Specify size on horizontal axis
int horizontalsize = horizontal.cols / scale;

// Create structure element for extracting horizontal lines through morphology operations
Mat horizontalStructure = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(horizontalsize,1));

// Apply morphology operations
erode(horizontal, horizontal, horizontalStructure, Point(-1, -1));
dilate(horizontal, horizontal, horizontalStructure, Point(-1, -1));


// Show extracted horizontal lines
imshow("horizontal", horizontal);

// Specify size on vertical axis
int verticalsize = vertical.rows / scale;

// Create structure element for extracting vertical lines through morphology operations
Mat verticalStructure = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size( 1,verticalsize));

// Apply morphology operations
erode(vertical, vertical, verticalStructure, Point(-1, -1));
dilate(vertical, vertical, verticalStructure, Point(-1, -1));

// Show extracted vertical lines
// imshow("vertical", vertical);

// create a mask which includes the tables
Mat mask = horizontal + vertical;
//imshow("mask", mask);
// waitKey(5000);
// detectCells(mask);


    // find the joints between the lines of the tables, we will use this information in order to descriminate tables from pictures (tables will contain more than 4 joints while a picture only 4 (i.e. at the corners))
Mat joints;
bitwise_and(horizontal, vertical, joints);
imshow("joints", joints);

  // Find external contours from the mask, which most probably will belong to tables or to images
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(mask, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
vector<Mat> rois;

for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    // find the area of each contour
    double area = contourArea(contours[i]);

    // filter individual lines of blobs that might exist and they do not represent a table
    if(area < 100) // value is randomly chosen, you will need to find that by yourself with trial and error procedure
        continue;

    approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
    boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );

    // find the number of joints that each table has
    Mat roi = joints(boundRect[i]);

    vector<vector<Point> > joints_contours;
    findContours(roi, joints_contours, RETR_CCOMP, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // if the number is not more than 5 then most likely it not a table

    if(joints_contours.size() <= 4)
        continue;

    rois.push_back(rsz(boundRect[i]).clone());

    //drawContours( rsz, contours, i, Scalar(0, 0, 255), CV_FILLED, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
    rectangle( rsz, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0 );
}

for(size_t i = 0; i < rois.size(); ++i)
{

    /* Now I should detect cells inside each table
     * detecting checkmarks                             */
       imshow("roi", rois[i]);

       waitKey();

}
imshow("contours", rsz);
    waitKey();
return 0;
}
```

My idea is to find square regions starting from left to right, top to bottom and skip in this way the first and second columns, then measure the pixel density inside the rest of squares to the right to determine if cell is checkmarked or not.

The problem is that I'm unable to do that with openCV, I'm newbie in image processing :-) is therefore i asked for help.

Comment: try **Template matching**

Comment: Hi, they could be right using Template matching to detect rows but cell heigth could be variable due single line row or multi line row. My idea is to find square regions starting from left to right, top to bottom and skip in this way the first and second columns, then measure the pixel density inside the rest of squares to the right to determine if cell is checkmarked or not. The problem is that I'm unable to do that with openCV, I'm newbie in image processing :-)  is therefore i asked for help.

Comment: It is a wonderful way to start off. I was merely giving a suggestion to kickstart.